# Django Aggregate Query Include Zero Count

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-q

In my Django application, I'm trying to get a Count of all **Student** submitted **Paper**s, including students who have submitted NO papers (represented as count=0).

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
   idstudent = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   student_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Student Name')

class Paper(models.Model):
   idpaper = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
```

**Query Attempt 1: Returns only Students who have submitted Papers**

```
papers = Paper.objects.order_by('submission_date')
result = papers.values('student', student_name=F('student__student_name')).annotate(count=Count('student')).distinct().order_by('-count')
print(result)       

<QuerySet [{'idstudent': 1, 'student_name': '\nMichael Jordan\n', 'count': 4}, {'idstudent': 2, 'student_name': '\nSteve White\n', 'count': 2}, {'idstudent': 3, 'student_name': '\nHillary Clinton\n', 'count': 1}]>
```

**Query Attempt 2: Returns Students who have submitted 0 Papers, but the Count for every other Student is 1**

```
result = Student.objects.values('pk', student_name=F('student_name'))
    .annotate(
        count=Count(
            'pk',
            filter=Q(pk__in=Paper.objects.values('student')
            )
        )
    )
).order_by('-count')
print(result)

<QuerySet [{'idstudent': 1, 'student_name': '\nMichael Jordan\n', 'count': 1}, {'idstudent': 2, 'student_name': '\nSteve White\n', 'count': 1}, {'idstudent': 3, 'student_name': '\nHillary Clinton\n', 'count': 1}, , {'idstudent': 4, 'student_name': '\nDoug Funny\n', 'count': 0}, , {'idstudent': 5, 'student_name': '\nSkeeter Valentine\n', 'count': 0}]>
```

Along the same lines as **Attempt 2**, I also tried the following using `Sum(Case(` which yielded the same result, as I recognized that the **Attempt 2** raw SQL actually utilizes `Case(When`, but seems to *only* count when `Student.pk` is present in the `Paper.objects.values` "list" (while not accounting for *how many times* it is present).

```
result = Student.objects.values('pk', student_name=F('student_name')).annotate(
    count=Sum(
        Case(
            When(pk__in=Paper.objects.values('student'), then=1),
            default=0, output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    )
)

<QuerySet [{'idstudent': 1, 'student_name': '\nMichael Jordan\n', 'count': 1}, {'idstudent': 2, 'student_name': '\nSteve White\n', 'count': 1}, {'idstudent': 3, 'student_name': '\nHillary Clinton\n', 'count': 1}, , {'idstudent': 4, 'student_name': '\nDoug Funny\n', 'count': 0}, , {'idstudent': 5, 'student_name': '\nSkeeter Valentine\n', 'count': 0}]>
```

How might I adjust my query to include students who have submitted 0 papers while also maintaining the correct counts for students who have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Along the same lines as Attempt 2, I also tried the following using
>   Sum(Case( which yielded the same result, as I recognized that the
>   Attempt 2 raw SQL actually utilizes Case(When, but seems to only count
>   when Student.pk is present in the Paper.objects.values "list" (while
>   not accounting for how many times it is present).

Either I'm not understanding the problem/question, but your Attempt 2 example is filtering the count to only `Paper.objects.values "list"`, its normal to act like this ?

Have you tried with the simple:

```
Student.objects.annotate(num_papers=Count('paper'))
```

If you want to make an additional filter on the count, my suggestion is to use [subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) here is an example:

```
Student.objects.annotate(
    num_papers=Subquery(
        Paper.objects.filter(student=OuterRef('pk'))
            # The first .values call defines our GROUP BY clause
            # Its important to have a filtration on every field defined here
            # Otherwise you will have more than one row per group!
            # In this example we group only by student
            # and we already filtered by student.
            # any extra filtration you want should be make here too (before the grouping).
            .values('student')
            # Here we say: count how many rows we have per group 
            .annotate(cnt=Count('pk'))
            # Here we say: return only the count
            .values('cnt')
    )
)
```

Comment: Student.objects.annotate(num_papers=Count('paper_set'))

Comment: nop, its `paper`, `paper_set` is when you do prefetch.

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/), if you do the filter first, then the count will get filtered too. But if you filter, you wont get students w/o papers? I think the best way to get what you need is to use a subquery in order to do the count, that way you have the best precision on what to count on. I will post an update in my answer in order to give you an idea how to do it with a subquery.

Comment: I think what I failed to convey in my original question is will this still work if I query on a subset of papers? For example, ...Count('paper')).filter('paper__in=subset'). I think that's where I'm running into troube. I no longer seem to get the 0 counts in that case. What I'm ultimately trying to do is set up form filters with labels that show dymanic counts, and those counts are adjusted as fitlers are applied.

Comment: I've update the answer with a subquery example, if you still cant manage to do it, then I would probably need more code (from the form maybe) in order to get you.