# Django Form Validation Error When Filtering by Count

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I'm utilizing Django Forms for my web application's server-side filter functionality, and I've made a few customizations so that the checkboxes are rendered in the template with custom labels to include dynamic counts (representing # of student paper submissions), as follows:

[x] Doug Funny (5)
[ ] Skeeter Valentine (3)
[x] Patti Mayonnaise (1)
[ ] Roger Klotz (0)

Right now, the field's queryset will return Student names for students who haven't submitted any papers (count = 0). As this is a bit too expensive from a page loading / performance perspective (there's a lot of student names, and a lot of paper submissions), I've decided to tweak the queryset so as to ***not*** include Student names with 0 counts in the list. To make this change, I've simply added a new filter to the query (`.filter(count__gt=0)`).

```
students = Student.objects.annotate(
                num_papers=Coalesce(
                    Subquery(
                        Paper.objects.filter(student=OuterRef('pk'))
                            .values('student').filter(pk__in=date_subset).filter(pk__in=keyword_subset)
                            .annotate(cnt=Count('pk'))
                            .values('cnt')
                    )
                ,0)
            ).filter(count__gt=0)
```

This succesfully removes student's who haven't submitted any papers from the filter list. But now, once I select any other name in the list to filter on, I receive the following error:

{'studentCheckbox': [ValidationError(['Select a valid choice. 588 is not one of the available choices.'])]}

It seems that the form.is_valid() call in my view is triggered. But why would adding a simple filter on count cause this error? I've done a bit of Field and Widget subclassing, so perhaps I've introduced the error somewhere in there. Perhaps a discrepancy with the generic Model queryset defined in the instantiation of the MyModelMultipleChoiceField vs. the dynamic assignment in the **init** class? I've included my full FilterForms.py code below, with the FilterForms class defined at the bottom.

```
class MyModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'count'):
            self.widget.count = obj.count
        return "%s (%s)" % (obj, obj.count)

class MyMultiSelectWidget(widgets.SelectMultiple):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.count = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None, attrs=None):
       index = str(index) if subindex is None else "%s_%s" % (index, subindex)
       if attrs is None:
           attrs = {}
       option_attrs = self.build_attrs(self.attrs, attrs) if self.option_inherits_attrs else {}
       if selected:
           option_attrs.update(self.checked_attribute)
       if 'id' in option_attrs:
           option_attrs['id'] = self.id_for_label(option_attrs['id'], index)

       return {
           'name': name,
           'count': str(self.count),
           'value': value,
           'label': label,
           'selected': selected,
           'index': index,
           'attrs': option_attrs,
           'type': self.input_type,
           'template_name': self.option_template_name,
       }

class FiltersForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    studentCheckbox = MyModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=MyMultiSelectWidget, queryset=Student.objects.all(), required=False)
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        date_subset = kwargs.pop('date_subset', [])
        keyword_subset = kwargs.pop('keyword_subset', [])
        super(FiltersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        students = Student.objects.annotate(
            num_papers=Coalesce(
                Subquery(
                    Paper.objects.filter(student=OuterRef('pk'))
                        .values('student').filter(pk__in=date_subset).filter(pk__in=keyword_subset)
                        .annotate(cnt=Count('pk'))
                        .values('cnt')
                )
            ,0)
        ).filter(count__gt=0)

        self.fields['studentCheckbox'].queryset = students
```

**The stacktrace:**

```
[29/Jul/2020 02:51:10] "GET /webapp/?dateRadio=180&searchInput=&showBookmarks=None HTTP/1.1" 200 512113
{'studentCheckbox': [ValidationError(['Select a valid choice. 588 is not one of the available choices.'])]}
Internal Server Error: /webapp/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view webapp.views.filter.filter didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

**views.py:**

```
def filter(request):

   if request.method == 'GET':

      form = FilterForm(request.GET)

      if form.is_valid():
         date = form.cleaned_data['dateRadio']
         students = form.cleaned_data['studentCheckbox']
         keywords = form.cleaned_data['keywordCheckbox']
    
         df = Q()
         if date:
           start=datetime.today() - timedelta(int(date))
           end = datetime.today()
           df = Q(submission_date__range=(start, end))

         sf = Q()
         if students:
             sub = Q()
             for student in students:
                 sub |= Q(student=student)
             sf = sub

         kf = Q()
         if keywords:
             sub = Q()
             for k in keywords:
                 sub |= Q(keywords=k)
             kf = sub

         df = Submission.objects.order_by('submission_date').filter(df)
         sf = Submission.objects.order_by('submission_date').filter(sf)
         kf = Submission.objects.order_by('submission_date').filter(kf)

         form = FilterForm(request.GET, date_subset=df.values_list('pk', flat=True), student_subset=sf.values_list('pk', flat=True), keyword_subset=kf.values_list('pk', flat=True)) 

         context = {
            ...
            'filterForm' : form,
            ...
         }

         return render(request, 'index.html', context)

      else: # form is not valid
         #todo
         print(form.errors.as_data())
```

Comment: Your queryset for annotating Students with a count of related Papers seems a little over complicated, could you not just do `students = Student.objects.annotate(num_papers=Count('paper_set'))`?

Comment: I originally tried that (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62317457/django-aggregate-query-include-zero-count), but I forgot to include in the code above additional "pk__in" filters that are passed in by the view which allow me to query on a subset of data - thus the need for the more overcomplicated query. I've gone ahead and updated the queryset code above.

Comment: You can just pass those parameters in a standard `filter()` especially since you only want Students that have Papers

Comment: When I try students = Student.objects.annotate(count=Count('papers')).filter(papers__pk__in=date_subset).filter(papers__pk__in=keyword_subset), the resulting counts are not correct in that they are very large numbers. Additionally, I am still receiving the ValidationError above.

Comment: Put the filters before the annotate and pass `distinct=True` to the Count

Comment: Yep that fixed the counts, but the ValidationError still remains.

Comment: I can also confirm that the Student id listed in the error does indeed exist in the database. So right now I have: students = Student.objects.filter(papers__pk__in=date_subset).filter(papers__pk__in=keyword_subset).annotate(count=Count('papers', distinct=True))

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question, do you actually need `MyMultiSelectWidget`? Can you add the view where you are getting the error?

Comment: Yes, MyMultiSelectWidget is what allows me to expose the annotated count from the queryset in such a way that I can parse it separately from the option name in the the template. The odd thing is that the stacktrace doesn’t point to any specific line of code in my view or in my form. I've updated the original question with the stacktrace. The reason it doesn't return an HttpResponse is because I haven't added in any logic in the "else" condition of "if form.is_valid:" (in the view)

Comment: Add the view to the question

Comment: Posted. Stripped some irrelevent code out for readability.

Comment: @IainShelvington I've implemented a fix, but I'm a bit nervous in that I don't fully understand why it's happening. As described earlier, when the user selects a choice from the ModelMultipleChoiceField, the form validation fails. Upon closer inspection of the validation, there's an empty queryset for the studentCheckbox. I'm guessing this has to do with the fact that I'm dynamically changing querysets based on other form fields, but I would have thought that the queryset would default to what was defined in the initialization - Student.objects.all(). As a fix, I added the following to my view

Comment: def filter(request):

   if request.method == 'GET':
      form = FilterForm(request.GET)

      form.fields['studentCheckbox'].queryset = Student.objects.all()

      if form.is_valid():

Answer (score 0):

```
    else: # form is not valid
         #todo
         print(form.errors.as_data())
```

in this case you should `return form.errors.as_data()`
It states that the form invalid you returned nothing, hence causing the error.

Comment: The question remains of why is the form not valid based on the changes to the queryset...